# How to resize a custom UIView and maintain its custom draw in proportion?

Tags: ios

I have a custom view with some drawing on it.
I want to resize it to a new proportion and I want the pattern I drew in it's drawRect to also be resized by the same proportion.

Is there anyway I can accomplish this without refreshing and redrawing everything.

Comment: some drawing should have autoresizing masks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be happening for you automatically with the default `contentMode`, which is `UIViewContentModeScaleToFill`. `contentMode` determines how to adjust the cached bitmap without forcing a new call to `drawRect:`. Also see `contentStretch` which allows you to control which part of the view is scaled.

Answer (score 0):

you will have to redraw it for the new proportion.

For that you have to store the points that made the CGPath and scale the points according to the new proportion and render it again.

Redrawing CGPath needs attention.

- If you have used simple moveTopoint / AddlinePoint you can do it just by storing points in an array. You can scale and redraw it later.
- If you can used functions like addcurveTopoint  etc., storing points in array won't work.A general purpose way is needed.For that you have to use the CGpathApply function. You can see an example it here. http://www.mlsite.net/blog/?p=1312
- If you need to zoom and no interation neeeded you can take a scrrenshot and and zoom the image.