# How to scale custom drawings inside drawRect: 

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiview, core-graphics

I am having the same issue as [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9328359/how-to-resize-a-custom-uiview-and-maintain-its-custom-draw-in-proportion), and the provided solution doesn't resolve it (nor is it clear that it resolved it in the other SO question).

When you change the `.frame` size of a UIView, and you haven't changed the default `.contentMode`, then for sure is the custom drawing in `drawRect` (Quartz paths) supposed to scale with the size of the UIView? Mine does not. Now I can call `setNeedsDisplay` and it will redraw, but I'm looking for scaling that can be animated. Is this possible?

Instead, what is happening for me is that the Quartz drawings are simply cropped but maintain their size. I've tried directly setting `contentMode` as well as `clipsToBounds` and other experiments but no auto-scaling for Quartz occurs to me no matter what I try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Must be something else going on.. [Here's](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/11290499/anim.zip) a simple demo I threw together to double-check contentMode works as expected—sure enough, the backing bitmap scales up/down when contentMode is set to the default "scale to fill". And calling setNeedsDisplay on the view re-renders the image.

What other things are you doing with the view? (You haven't changed its contentStretch property, have you?) Are you doing anything with the view's layer? Have you checked that the contentMode on the view really is UIViewContentModeScaleToFill? Also, are you animating the frame of the view itself, or a superview?

Comment: i have downloaded your sample but the simulator option is not available on it for me in Xcode, any idea why? I noticed you are setNeedsDisplay after the animation. Did it not scale until you did this, or you were doing this to redraw to make a better resolution after animation?

Comment: Huh, that's weird. I'm in Xcode 4.3.2, using the 5.1 simulator. You could just create a new ipad project and drag the source and xib files in.. It scales up and down in the animation. If you comment out the setNeedsDisplay call, its stays scaled up or down as per the frame setting, but if it's been scaled up it's blurry and jaggy.

Comment: thanks for the help. my issue appeared to be that I was setting the frame of the custom view before setNeedsDisplay had finished, or something. Not sure. I tried putting a time in place to make sure the view was initialized before scaling it and sure enough it worked.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to overwrite **drawLayer**

```
- (void)drawLayer:(CALayer*)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx
{
    [super drawLayer:layer inContext:ctx];

    /*here to change self.frame
        self.frame = CGRectMack(a, b, c, d);
    */
}
```